# Differentiability of a multivariable function.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have to show that $$f(x,y,z) = x^2y + y^2z + z^2x$$ is differentiable everywhere using the fact that is can be expressed as $$f(\vec{x}+\vec{h}) - f(\vec{x}) = \vec{A}.\vec{h} + o(\vec{h})$$ now I have done this and got on the right hand side:

$$(2xy+z^2,x^2+2yz,y^2 + 2zx).(h_1.h_2,h_3) + (...)$$

This would be great if the $(...)$ was all in $h_1,h_2,h_3$ but it has $x,y,z's $ in it. How do I deal with this? as it isn't a vector function of just $h$??

Comment: Your function is a real valued valued function, so  why you are writing a dot  product ??

Comment: @Nizar -- He is writing the action of the derivative on the vector $h$, as he was asked to.

Comment: @HMPARTICLE -- All you want from the $o(h)$ part is that it be a function of $h=(h_1,h_2,h_3)$ such that if you divide it by the norm of $h$ and let $h\to 0$, it will tend to zero. Now this function will depend on $(x,y,z)$ and might be not the most simple expression ever to be encountered, but do not despair.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but for the time being, I am beaten